# Change video source on TV using SCART

Tags: openelec, composite-video

I have a model B Raspberry Pi running OpenELEC v4.2.1 connected by the composite output to the SCART input of my TV using one of these:

http://www.tandyonline.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/o/composite-to-scart.png

I have read that SCART can automatically change the video source on the TV by sending a voltage through pin 8 of the SCART connection, see http://hackaday.com/2011/04/26/scart-hack-automatically-selects-tvs-av-mode/.

Is there anyway to do this in OpenELEC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

> *Pup says:*
>   *April 26, 2011 at 8:52 am*
>
> Slightly misleading title since this is selecting aspect ratio, not A/V mode.
>   Incidentally, the only kind of SCART connections for games consoles that don’t do auto-switching are the A/V composite adaptors – the tiny SCART bricks with 3 RCA sockets. [...]

That's one of the comments. The 8 pin on SCART selects the aspect ratio, and the auto-switch to the AV mode on the TV depends on the TV. Some TVs do this automatically, some not.

Comment: That is not the full story, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART#blanking_and_switching) the voltage applied to Pin-8 (from a source with a 1KOhm impedance) to the TV's SCART connector, does both A/V mode and aspect ratio: 0–2V means no signal, or internal bypass; 4.5V–7V (nominal 6 V) means a widescreen (16:9) signal and 9.5V–12V (nominal 12 V) means a normal (4:3) signal.